# Favorite Clipboard Extension

Tags: clipboard

I use the [ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) clipboard extension when I'm writing code, it's great for copying variable names, data and more.  What  other clipboard extensions to people use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ditto is still the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own tool written in Tcl/tk. It only saves text, but it allows me to access the clipboard as a scrollable stack. In addition, I can edit the contents of a clipping before pasting, and when I right-click an item it parses the text and attempts to give me a useful menu. For example, if the contents begins with "http" the menu includes "visit in browser").

Plus, it works on all platforms that I personally use (win, *nix, mac). Wrote it back in 1999 or so and still runs fine today.

Comment: It's actually been on the net since '99 and I don't think I've touched the code since. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to find it. There's really nothing there that couldn't be cobbled together by a competent programmer in an afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

[ClipX](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/) for Windows.
I am looking for another one for Linux.